# TYPO3 7.6.15 - TypoScript cannot properly close brackets in template setup

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am having a difficulties wih closing brackets using typoscript in template setup of TYPO3 version 7.6.15.

For Instance:

```
lib.fluidContent { #this is displayed red as it wasn´t closed
  partialRootPaths {
    10 = fileadmin/templates/content/partials
  }
}

plugin.tx_form { #this is displayed red as it wasn´t closed
  partialRootPaths {
    20 = fileadmin/templates/form/partials
  }
}
```

I am using PHP version 5.6.28

Thanks in Advance!
Denis

Answer (score 4):

Probably a typo. Check brackets in preceding template. Probably you have somewhere unnecessary bracket. See in Template -> Object Browser, if this won't suggest properly where the problem is, try to unload some of your typoscript, check when it stops to happen to find out in which one is the problem.